# Making multiple columns in pandas based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set a pandas dataframe column into an index. Since it is a categorical column, I would like to collapse all column in same category. For example:

```
df

  col1   Set_Index    col2
0    1        A         'a'
1    2        B         'b'
2    3        A         'c'
3    4        B         'd'
```

The new df must look like:

Edit: I forgot to put the default index in my first draft of the output needed in final output. It must be finally look like:

```
new_df

             col1      col2
Set_Index 
   A      0    1       'a'
          2    3       'c'
   B      1    2       'b'
          3    4       'd'
```

I tried to use the groupby() function but it didn't help much.

Comment: It looks like you want `Set_Index` to be the index of the DataFrame--have you tried `DataFrame.set_index()`?

Comment: if you have unique values in col2, then try `df.pivot_table(index=['set_index', 'col2'])`.

Comment: @vbrises I have multiple columns (col1 and col2), so instead of a pivot table, I worked with `reorder_levels` to get the required `Set_Index` before the default index. It finally gave me the output in desired format I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, you would probably be interested in `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` and `reindex` [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the 'Set_Index' column as index, drop it and sort the rows based on the new indices.

```
df_new = df.set_index(df.Set_Index).drop(columns=['Set_Index']).sort_index()
df_new
```

And you will have the following df_new:

[image]

As far as I know, every row should have an index and I would not know how to create the df_new you indicated (without index for row 2 and 4).

You can read more about indexing in pandas here:
https://brohrer.github.io/dataframe_indexing.html